# Angular 6, call API every few seconds or receive new data from subscription every few seconds

Tags: angular, angular6

Given a simple HTTP call:

```
object: Object;

this.http.get<any>( this._globals.apiServer + 'api/data', {responseType: 'json'})
.subscribe((resp: any) => {
    this.object = resp;
})
```

How can I modify it so every e.g 3 seconds object is refreshed with brand new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of either `SetTimeout` or `SetInterval`;

- If you want the next request to action exactly 3 seconds after the
  last, use `SetTimeout`
- If you want the request to get exactly every 3 seconds regardless of
  how long the last request took (or even if it is still going), use `SetInterval`

For instance;

```
object: Object;
requestTimeout;
refreshObject() {
    this.http.get<any>(this._globals.apiServer + 'api/data', {responseType: 'json'})
        .subscribe((resp: any) => {
            this.object = resp;

            // Call again in 3 seconds
            this.requestTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.refreshObject(), 3000);
        }, (error) => {
            // Something went wrong
            console.error(error);

            // Try again in 3 seconds
            this.requestTimeout = setTimeout(() => this.refreshObject(), 3000);
        });
}

// Stop the pending request 
ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.requestTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(this.requestTimeout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use the interval observable and just switch off of it.

```
interval(3000).pipe(
  switchMapTo(this.http.get<any>( this._globals.apiServer + 'api/data', {responseType: 'json'}))
)
.subscribe((resp: any) => {
    this.object = resp;
})
```

notes:

1. this observable needs to be unsubscribed if the component / service is destroyed.
2. this will start after 3 seconds, to begin right away do `timer(0, 3000)` instead